# Android RelativeLayout not center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a problem about TextView in RelativeLayout is not center, (only some objects)

First, I'm use ListAdapter for ListView.

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Menu> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Menu> o) {
        super(c, 0, o);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (v == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        } else {
            view = v;
        }
        final Menu data = this.getItem(position);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        ImageView background = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.background);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView subtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        subtitle.setText(data.getSubTitle());
        title.setText(data.getTitle());
        background.setImageDrawable(data.getBackground());
        icon.setImageDrawable(data.getIcon());
        return view;
    }
}
```

and, My row.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="82dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="83dip"
        android:src="@drawable/mediumorchid" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="35dip"
        android:layout_height="35dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_discard" />
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl1"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/width"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dip"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fl1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fl1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fl1"
    android:background="#ecf0f1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:text="Pure"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="2dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/width"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/width"
    android:background="@drawable/cdivider" >
</FrameLayout>
```

This xml's Graphic Design [image]

But in Device(example grouper) , i discover this problem. [image]
In some object, (example see Help ~) Was centered properly. but, other objects, wasn't centered properly.

and i discover this problem another device(different resolution, size, Android version, density).

What can i do solve this problem??

Comment: Thank you for uploading images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` for **subtitle** `TextView`

```
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Answer (score 0):

or this

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Comment: No you cannot use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` It'll overlap the above `TextView`.